# Re-bind VIM system clipboard register yank/paste keys

Tags: vim, key, system, yank

Instead of typing

```
"*y
"*p
```

To copy code from one file to another, what kind of VIM shortcut would you guys recommend implementing in my .vimrc which won't interfere with many other motions?

Answer (score 0):

No shortcut. Stick this into your config, then just use the normal `y` and `p`:

```
set clipboard+=unnamedplus
```

(`:help clipboard`, `:help clipboard-unnamedplus`)

(Some prefer `unnamed` to `unnamedplus`.)

Comment: Now whatever I yank in vim doesn't go into clipboard

Comment: That's... strange. No idea why it wouldn't.

Comment: Oh, lemme check one thing: is your Vim compiled with clipboard feature? You can see it by running `vim --version` and seeing `+clipboard`, or within Vim using `:echo has('clipboard')` and hoping for `1`.

Answer (score 0):

I use `<C-y>` as an operator that performs the yank into `"*`. I've not bound paste, though I suppose one could do

```
nnoremap <C-P> "*p
```

or something similar. Pasting, though, has so many variants that I'm reluctant to "limit" myself. (I use `]op`—from tpope/unimpaired—followed by Command-V sometimes, as well as other paste methods.)

For `<C-y>`, I have the following script in `~/.vim/plugin/pbcopy_op.vim`:

```
if exists('g:loaded_pbcopy_op')
  finish
endif
let g:loaded_pbcopy_op = 1

nnoremap <silent> <C-y> :set operatorfunc=pbcopy#operator<CR>g@
nnoremap <silent> <C-y>y :set operatorfunc=pbcopy#operator<CR>g@_
nnoremap <silent> <C-y><C-y> :set operatorfunc=pbcopy#operator<CR>g@_
vnoremap <silent> <C-y> :<C-u>call pbcopy#operator(visualmode(), 1)<CR>
```

And the function definition (`~/.vim/autoload/pbcopy.vim`):

```
function! pbcopy#operator(type, ...) abort

  let l:visual = a:0

  if l:visual
    normal! gv"*y
  elseif a:type == 'line'
    '[,']yank *
  else " char
    normal! `[v`]"*y
  endif

endfunction
```

---

If you're copying from one file to another *inside the same vim instance*, just use `y` and `p`.

---

Last alternative: I use `tmux(1)`, so I frequently yank things into tmux's buffers.

Then, since I have tpope/tbone installed, I can do `:Tput`.